# Eulers totient functions

Tags: totient-function

I dont understand that how did they come to following conclusion whats the thing that i need to know

[image: Image of the result]

Comment: It's supposed to be $\phi(5)$, not $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Do you know [Euler's totient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?